# Executing php commands under proxy with automatic URL.

Tags: php, symfony, cmd, proxy

First of all, i would ask you to be as clear as you can, im still junior at this and some concepts are still hard for me. I will be as clear as i can as well.
So here is the deal. Im working under a proxy with user authentication, which i cant disable. I can direct download programs but console is another story. 
Im trying to install symfony 3.4 with the php command:

```
php -r "file_put_contents('symfony', file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer'));
```

Php (7.1.23) seems to work fine (php -version returns ok )
I've set the global variables https_proxy and http_proxy (my proxy is working with the non-safe protocol, but i've set both to the same direction http:// .... accelerated_pac_base.pac). In caps and in lower just in case. 
The proxy is correctly configured in all my browsers with no trouble.

The closest approach i've reached so far is coding it in directly in cmd (server from proxy extracted the server-port from the .pac file) with the code below:

```
php -r "file_put_contents('symfony',file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer',False, stream_context_create(['proxy' => 'my_proxy_server:80', 'request_fulluri' => true,'header'=> 'Proxy-Authorization: Basic '.base64_encode('my_proxy_user:my_proxy_password')])));"
```

this is showing some warnings with errors like

```
PHP Warning : stream_context_creat(): options should have the form ["wrappername"]["optionname"] = $value in Command line code on line 1
Warning : stream_context_creat(): options should have the form ["wrappername"]["optionname"] = $value in Command line code on line 1

PHP Warning : file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses : getaddrinfo failed : (error in spanish which i translated into: "This is usually a temporary eror during host name resolution meaning local server didnt got an answer from an authoritative server") In Command line code on line 1.
Warning : file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses : getaddrinfo failed : (error in spanish which i translated into: "This is usually a temporary eror during host name resolution meaning local server didnt got an answer from an authoritative server") In Command line code on line 1.

PHP Warning : file_put_contents (symfony): failed to open stream: Permission denied in Command line code on line 1
PHP Warning : file_put_contents (symfony): failed to open stream: Permission denied in Command line code on line 1
```

errors duplicated by the way (i dont know if is normal or could mean something)
Also tried changing the automatic URL for the server-port, without server settings, with some installers... nothing seem to work
I have this issue with symfony and with the composer. 
Either a fix on my code or some different approach will be very appreciated. If you need some more info just let me know, im working with windows 10 and the code i posted has no syntax errors.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tell your boss you need direct access to the internet without some crazy corporate proxy in between. If he tells you that is not possible, change your employer ASAP. Run away literally. This will bite you all the way down. Srsly.

Comment: Already tried as well. The security protocols are way above for the guys in charge. My immediate boss told me he had already tried formal petitions and wont do, so i have to use this workaround.

Comment: As I said before: RUN!

Comment: Maybe you can use your mobile phone as an mobile access point?

Comment: The point here is that i need it to have it configured to run on corporate machine, without depending on external sources which will always run one time. For some installation could work but i need either way to be able to do it by the means given. 
I think this problem is only mine for not being able to configure it accurately, since the desktop applications can download stuff im pretty sure it can be done but i dont know how...